# How to customized function key for Acer Aspire in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, acer-aspire, function-keys

Many times, when copy and paste, i tend to click <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, is there a way to map <kbd>fn</kbd> key to control key, when I do not need the <kbd>fn</kbd> key? 
Of course sometimes I need it to say adjust brightness, volume etc, and only then I am allow to map it back.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: How would any software know when you do or do not need it?

Comment: I mean by explicitly turning fn on and off. When turning off, it is function as control.

Comment: There is no way that I know of. Afaik the fn-key is controlled in hardware, not software.